# jQuery - check if selected row is last visible row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

previously i checked whether a row is last row in a table like this in a condition:

```
$row.is(':last-child')
```

which works fine.

Now, i have a requirement where some of the rows in the table are hidden - now i have to check whether a specific row is the **last visible** row in the table.

I tried with this:

```
$row.is(':visible:last-child')
```

but not that successfull. Does someone have a clue?

Comment: should work, just like `$("#question").is(':visible:last-child')` on this page returns `false` but `$("#question").is(':visible:first-child')` returns `true`. _How_ doesn't it work?

Comment: I have a strange feeling, but I think he may misunderstand what the :visible selector does.  It doesn't check if something is off the page (ie. scrolling).  It just sees if something is not hidden on the page.  A pure shot in the dark but hey, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx everybody for the quick feedback. I could solve it with the following:

```
$row.parent().find('tr:visible').last().attr('data-id') is $row.attr('data-id')
```

(it's in a loop)

@falsarella your answer i guess works fine - is a bit complicated, but it works apparently.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know I could use id comparison, but OK. A fiddle would be great to help other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because the `last-child` is `display: none;`.

One approach is to iterate the childs to find the index of the last visible child **[(see fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vhD8K/)** :

```
var $rows = $('td');
var $rowsReverse = $($rows.get().reverse());

var $lastVisibleIndex = -1;
$rowsReverse.each(function(index) {
    if ($lastVisibleIndex == -1 && $(this).is(':visible')) {
        $lastVisibleIndex = $rowsReverse.length - index - 1;
    }
});

$rows.each(function(index) {
    var $row = $(this);
    if (index == $lastVisibleIndex) {            
        $row.addClass('red');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`$(element).is(":visible").last();`

or

`$(element:visible).last();`

If that doesn't work, let me know.